# How to find advanced info about a network I am connected to?

Tags: windows, networking, dhcp

I currently have a laptop connected to a WPA2 Enterprise wireless network, and I'm trying to connect a new device.  There's no wireless set-up guide for the type of device I'm trying to connect, so I would like to manually enter in all the necessary settings.  I need to know:

- EAP Method (PEAP vs. TTLS)
- Phase 2 Authentication if applicable (PAP vs. MSCHAPv2)
- CA Certificate if applicable
- Connection type (DHCP vs. Static)

  - If connection type is Static, I would need to know:
  - IP Address
  - Subnet Mask
  - Router
  - DNS

My assumption is that because I already have access to a laptop connected to / set up for the same network, there must be some way to retrieve that information about the network from my laptop while connected.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm using windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the wireless network configuration of the connected machine. For that you can navegate throught the gui or you can type in run (windows key+R) "ncpa.cpl". This command open directly the appropiate window. Double click the wireless connection and click on details, and you can see if this machine is connected using dhcp or static ip, ip address, mask, ... and in wireless properties button, security tab you can see the other details (EAP method, etc)

http://www.howto-connect.com/how-to-find-wifi-password-in-windows-8/